# Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization condition from the WKB approximation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, quantization, semiclassical

How can one prove the Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization condition

$$ \oint p~dq ~=~2\pi n \hbar $$

from the WKB ansatz solution $$\Psi(x)~=~e^{iS(x)/ \hbar}$$ for the Schroedinger equation?

With $S$ the action of the particle defined by Hamilton-Jacobi equation

$$ \frac{\partial S}{\partial t}+ \frac{(\nabla S)^{2} }{2m}+V(x)~=~0 .$$

Answer (score 13):

The semiclassical/Bohr-Sommerfeld/Wilson-Sommerfeld/[WKB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation)/[EBK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93Brillouin%E2%80%93Keller_method) quantization rule and connection formulas are discussed in numerous textbooks. The discrete quantization condition follows from requiring single-valuedness of the wavefunction. Note that quantization formula gets modified by the [metaplectic correction](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metaplectic+correction+%28in+geometric+quantization%29)/[Maslov index](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Maslov+index) because of turning points.

For an elementary treatment, see e.g. Refs. 1-7 below. For a rigorous treatment, see [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27492/2451) Phys.SE post.

References:

1. D. Griffiths, *Intro to QM,* 2nd ed, 2004; chapter 9.
2. L.D. Landau & E.M. Lifshitz, *QM,* Vol. 3, 3rd ed, 1981; chapter VII.
3. A. Galindo & P. Pascual, *QM II,* 1991; chapter 9.
4. P. Cvitanovic et. al., *Chaos: Classical and Quantum,* 2013; sections 37.1-36.7. [Gutzwiller trace formula](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=gutzwiller+trace+formula) is discussed in chapter 39. The pdf file is available at [www.chaosbook.org](http://chaosbook.org).
   (Since the book is continuously updated the chapter number may shift in the future.)
5. H.S. Friedrich, *[Theoretical Atomic Physics](http://www.google.com/search?q=Friedrich+Theoretical+Atomic+Physics),* 1998; section 1.5.3.
6. R.G. Littlejohn, [*The WKB Method*](http://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/1112/notes/wkb.pdf), lecture notes, 2019.
7. [Weyl law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_law).