# bohr-sommerfeld quantiztion condition from semiclasical WKB

Tags: semiclassical

in WKB the quantization conditions are

$$ \oint _{C} p.dq =2\pi n \hbar \tag{1}$$

and the wave function is $$ \Psi(x)= exp \left( \frac{iS[y(x)]}{\hbar} \right), \tag{2}$$

but what boundary conditions must I impose to this wave function if I want to obtain borh sommerfeld conditions ??

Comment: WKB gives Bohr-Sommerfeld if you construct a bound state, i.e. the classically allowed region of the potential is finite.

Comment: OP's question (v1) is discussed in many QM textbook on WKB. See e.g. the references given in [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64212/2451) related Phys.SE post by OP.