# Any good reference on Maslov index (or Morse index)?

Tags: mathematical-physics, differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, hamiltonian-formalism, topology

Any good reference on [Maslov index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_Grassmannian#Maslov_index) (or [Morse index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory))?
I have some basic knowledge of differential geometry, calculus of variation. So is there any good reference for me?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64212/2451