# What is the relation between physics of music instruments and quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, acoustics

I have read that when quantum mechanics were emerged as a separate field in physics, physicists of that time had a developped theory about sound and vibrating strings which they implemented to describe the new phenomena.

Is this the case, or is it an exaggeration? If yes, in which way were the borrowed notions implemented?

To make the question more clear: Musical instruments theory and quantum mechanics share the same maths and if yes, which are these maths?

Comment: If you like this question you may also enjoy reading [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/318621/2451) Phys.SE post.

Comment: *Where* have you read this? Please always include your sources when possible.

Comment: @ACuriousMind It is on several places on google.

Comment: @KyleOman Nobody asked your justification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an exaggeration really.  Understanding musical instruments involves solving wave equations with boundary conditions (for instance for a vibrating string, or a column of air in a pipe), and in particular understanding that any solution can be represented in terms of a (generally infinite) sum of basis solutions.  Quantum Mechanics, in one of its two early formulations, also involves solving wave equations with boundary conditions, and the same notion of basis states & sums of them applies there.

But really what this is saying is that the techniques of formulating & solving certain kinds of wave equation matter in both areas: perhaps these techniques had first been developed for understanding musical instruments, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to include the two wave equations/solutions to highlihgt similarities & differences.

Comment: @KyleKanos: yes it would.  I'll do so this evening if I have time.