# Bohr’s Quantisation Condition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wave-particle-duality, wavelength, semiclassical

I am a grade 12 student from India and my physics textbook does not delve deep in the bohrs quantisation condition but has given us a paragraph to figure out what it is:

> “Consider Motion of an electron in a circular orbit of radius r around the nucleus of the atom. According to De Broglie hypothesis, the electron is also associated with wave character. Hence the circular orbit can be taken to be a stationary energy state only if it contains an integral number of De Broglie wavelengths.”

I can’t comprehend or understand this explanation. I know what wavelength and de Broglie’s hypothesis is, but why should their be an integral number of wavelengths in a particular orbit? What is a stationery energy state?

Comment: It's similar to a standing wave on a stretched string where there has to be a whole number of half wavelengths.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/318621/2451