# Semiclassical approximation self-study

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, semiclassical

Can someone give a review of good books to learn semiclassical physics? Somehow, I would like to know if there is a text at the level of Lanczos or Gelfand. By this, I mean that I am interested in the combination of semiclassical physics with variational problems in the context of QFT (with the variational problems at the level of the aforementioned authors).

If there exist semiclassical books based on quantum optics, it will also be fine. The point is a book in which one can do the maths and later with an advanced treatise formalized what has been learned.

The book *Semi-Classical Approximation in Quantum Mechanics* by [Maslov and Fedoriuk](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9789027712196) seems to be the standard reference, but it's quite dated and advanced.

I don't look for specific chapters of books where this is treated, I am looking for a basic monograph which is mainly focused on this topic.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/64212/2451

Comment: Uhmm I am looking for a more complete treatise, like the book by Maslov and Fedourik, but this is too advanced.