# Calculating energy eigenvalues when potential is given

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, schroedinger-equation, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

So our teacher claimed that if we have a Potential of the form $V(x)= x^\nu$ then the Energy is of the form $E={2\nu \over \nu+2}$
Can anyone break up the math for this problem?

Comment: Do you mean the ground state energy? If $\nu$ is an odd integer the energy is not bounded below.

Comment: Yes the bound state energy

Comment: $x^\nu$ in imaginary if $x<0$ and $\nu$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: V actually varies with x in,this manner.. So you can ignore the non trivial solutions

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you consider only even powers of $x$ (for odd powers there are no bound states) the behaviour you describe comes from the Born-Sommerfeld condition. This is described in the Wikipedia article [Old quantum theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_quantum_theory), and there is [a related question on this site](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/27492/rigorous-proof-of-bohr-sommerfeld-quantization).

Suppose $E$ is the energy of your system, and $\pm X$ are the turning points where $E = V(X)$, then for your system the Born-Sommerfeld condition states:

$$ \int_{-X}^{+X} p \, dx = nh $$

where the momentum $p$ is given by:

$$ p(x) = \sqrt{2m(E - V(x))} $$